# How are user search results ordered?

Tags: discussion, search, users

My name on stackexchange is Bruno, however there are multiple Brunos on stackexchange.
When I search for Bruno there are many results but none are me.
Is the search delimited by reputation? So if my reputation were a million and I searched for Bruno I would be the first on the search results?

Comment: Even Jon Skeet doesn't have 1,000,000 reputation... *yet*.

Comment: @Matt: That's not true! His reputation just overflowed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you referring to https://stackexchange.com/search?q=bruno?  AFAIK, that's the only way to search all the sites simultaneously.  It's just a Google search, so all the normal Google SEO stuff applies.  If your name is in the URL of your profile, your profile has been linked and mentioned a lot, and you've made a lot of posts (which have links through your user card back to your profile), you'll rank highly there.  It's roughly the same behavior as you would see at a generic Google search like http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackexchange.com+user+bruno

I rarely, if ever, use the Google search tool.  Instead, I use the syntax documented on the [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search):

```
user:<userID>
```

to search for posts by a specific user.  A userID is the number in a profile URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/888737/bruno
                               ^^^^^^-Here
```

so the search ["user:888737"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A888737) brings up all your posts. If you're logged in, ["user:me"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame) also works.

Add additional search terms to filter your posts.  For example, ["user:888737 [ms-access] [excel]"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A888737+%5Bms-access%5D+%5Bexcel%5D) brings up all your posts with both the [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) and [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) tags.

Comment: I'm just thinking in terms of user:Bruno. For example, if I told a friend that I'm on stackoverflow and casually told them to search for me by firstname. So i guess the answer is that it would be possible if I have one of the highest reputations for my name. Also I could just change my display name to something unique and it should work nicely user:uniqueName vs user:888737

Comment: @Bruno - You could change your username to 888737, that would certainly be unique.

Comment: Also, your question is less than an hour old.  You haven't given other users time to post anything, so you can't know whether this is the best solution to your problem.  I'm thankful that you accepted my answer, but it's usually better to wait 24-48 hours to accept something to give others time to answer your post.  For instance, there's no way that the devs could have implemented, tested, and uploaded a fix that causes a search for ["user:bruno"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3ABruno) to do what you want.